# Use facebox along with $.ajax

Tags: jquery, facebox

I used facebox and $.ajax inside HighChart event, but it run only one time and cannot run the next time. I guess the problem happen when facebox is closed. Anybody has an experience with this sort of problem? Thank you :-)

```
point:{
                            events:{
                                click:function(){
                                    jQuery.facebox({'ajax':this.options.url});
                                    $.ajax({
                                        type: "GET",
                                        url: 'GetHighChart.aspx',
                                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                        dataType: "html",
                                        success: function (d) {
                                            //alert("Done");
                                            $("#container1").html(d);
                                        }
                                    });       
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem. I solved it by including the facebox plugin again in the HTML that was being called in the facebox. Ugly fix, but it works.

Comment: can you explain more about your solution :D